# Wait for different conditions on same wait queue or use separate wait queue for each condition?

Tags: linux-kernel

Looks like `wait_event_interruptible()` allows user to wait for different conditions on the same wait queue. Is it better to have one wait queue for each condition the user wants to wait for?

Comment: If you have different threads waiting on the same waitqueue but for different conditions, then you cannot awoke just a single thread when one of conditions becomes true: the first thread in the queue may wait for another condition. You need to awoke all threads (with `wake_up_all` or similar), so every thread may recheck its condition and re-wait if needed. But this is quite inefficient to wake up all threads, when all-but-one will repeat waiting.

Comment: thx for your input. I am having exact issues as your described when using a single wait queue for multiple conditions. So looks like it's better to have a dedicated wait queue for each condition to wait.